# How can I find all unnamed people in Photos on iOS (not on macOS)?

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app

Is there a way on iOS (not on macOS) to list all photos that have people detected in them but for which the people haven't been associated with a name / contact yet?

Perhaps a smart album or a third-party app?

Comment: You can use Google Photos. This will detect photos with people in them and create an album for that in the Google Photos app. You can name each person and also choose not to if you would like.

Comment: Thanks Todd. This could be an option for tagging all my photos, however I'm tagging them using the Photos app on iOS, and it's been working well so far. My specific need is to find the photos that can be tagged but for which I haven't yet assigned a person. I've gone through most photos already, but for a large library it's impossible to get a list of only the photos that have faces in them and for which the face doesn't have a name.